# Result of MySQL PASSWORD() in phpMyAdmin differs from result of PASSWORD() in MySQL CLI

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I run query `SELECT PASSWORD('demo11') FROM mytable` through the web interface of my phpMyAdmin 3.2.2.1 instance, it gives the result

```
PASSWORD('demo11')
*C85514894FD44DF933FC33F84DCB047C884A7095.
```

When I run the same query on the same machine through MySQL CLI, I got

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| PASSWORD('demo11')                        |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *41BDDCB1E7FDB4CC929E949E0F5A5FBDB57E4EEA |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does phpMyAdmin convert querys before running them?

This is definitely PMA/MySQL combination issue, as the same PMA (3.2.2.1) on a different machine (created from the same AWS image) returns "correct" result (*41BDDCB1E7FDB4CC929E949E0F5A5FBDB57E4EEA).

As a hint: some time ago I ran mysqlrepair on a database in question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. phpMyAdmin submits something like this:

```
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
SET collation_connection = 'utf32_unicode_ci';
SELECT PASSWORD('demo11') FROM mytable;
```

When I omit collation setting or set utf8_unicode_ci the query returns correct value.